# What does 3 '/'s in a row do in C#?

Tags: c#, comments

I was coding along in lala land when suddenly I typed a 3'd '/' in a comment. Originally a comment goes **green** with 2 '/'s **:**

[image: Subject1]

But with the third dash, it goes **grey** '///' **:**

[image: Subject2]

Does this have any specific meaning? Or did it just change color?

Comment: Of course `///` is just about the colour. Just as `""` is about making things red ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It denotes an XmlComment, more of which can be read about on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx). For example,

```
/// <summary>
/// Method summary  - a method that does something
/// </summary>
/// <param name="i">Description of param</param>
/// <param name="s">Description of param</param>
/// <returns>An object of some sort or other</returns>
public object AMethod(int i, string s)
{
}
```

Edit: as suggested below, it also provides [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) guidance, as the image below demonstrates.

[image]

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that as well as generating documentation, these also provide details for Intellisense popups in Visual Studio.

Comment: Nicely done too. Though how you work with that colour scheme... ;)

Comment: @DavidM lol I'm trying several out to see which I like best. Just cant get on with default white background and some of the more popular black background alts

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm trying variants on vibrant ink, which is slightly off black, but it's not quite there for me yet...

Answer (score 5):

Three-slash comments are for the documentation builder. You can generate documentation of your APIs straight from the source. You can document what your API does, what parameters it takes, what exceptions it throws, etc. right in your source. Microsoft provides tools to verify that your documentation is in sync with the actual API. For example, if you add, remove, or rename a parameter, but forget to document the change, you will get a warning.

This is how you generate documentation from these tags using Visual Studio: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`///` is for XML comment. it provides an XML formatted comment. You can also create XML document from this by using the `/doc:` options while compiling from this like

```
csc /doc:filedoc.xml program.cs
```